# Ejb Websphere login returns empty subject

Tags: java, authentication, ejb, websphere

I'm trying to get a subject to execute an EJB deployed on my instance of WebSphere.

As documentation says, i'm trying authentication with this

```
Subject subject;
LoginContext lc = null;
InitialContext initialContext = createInitialContext(serverName, serverPort);
initialContext.lookup(""); 
lc = new LoginContext(JAAS_MODULE, new WSCallbackHandlerImpl(userId, "", password));
lc.login();
subject = lc.getSubject();



InitialContext createInitialContext(String serverName, String serverPort) throws NamingException {
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);

    String providerUrl = String.format("corbaloc:iiop:%s:%s", serverName, serverPort);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);

    return new InitialContext(env);
}
```

After the lc.login call, the subject does not contain any principal inside. I just receive an empty principal which is useless to execute the ejb.
Anyone else faced this problem?

Comment: Are you using traditional WebSphere? If so, do you have security enabled?   Are you using WebSphere Liberty?  If so, what features do you have enabled?

Comment: I'm using tradition websphere...EJB is deployed for everyone.

Comment: What's the name of the LoginContext you're using?  Your code shows: `new LoginContext(JAAS_MODULE,...`  but not clear what that value is. Unless it's one of the ones available by default like ["WSLogin"](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tsec_pacs.html), I'd think you'd need an administrator to add it to your config.

Comment: Yeah it is WSLogin